# sql server 2008, how to get rid of duplications when inner join 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

here's my query. when I inner join 2 tables, there's no problem.

```
 SELECT S.* ,
        U.Avatar ,
        U.Displayname ,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY S.Id DESC ) rownum
 FROM   dbo.Smoothie AS S
        INNER JOIN dbo.[User] AS U ON S.UserId = U.Id
 WHERE  S.IsPublic = 1
        AND S.Status = 3
        AND S.UserId = 2
```

then, I added another inner join.  now, I got alot duplications.

```
SELECT  S.* ,
        U.Avatar ,
        U.Displayname,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY S.Id DESC ) rownum
FROM    dbo.Smoothie AS S
        INNER JOIN dbo.[User] AS U ON S.UserId = U.Id
        INNER JOIN dbo.Favorite AS F ON U.Id = F.UserId
WHERE   S.IsPublic = 1
        AND S.Status = 3
        AND F.UserId = 2
```

one solutions is  to use distinct. however, I have to comment out row_number, i need that row_number to do paging.  is there another way to get rid of duplication?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT S.* ,
        U.Avatar ,
        U.Displayname 
        -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY S.Id DESC ) rownum
FROM    dbo.Smoothie AS S
        INNER JOIN dbo.[User] AS U ON S.UserId = U.Id
        INNER JOIN dbo.Favorite AS F ON U.Id = F.UserId
WHERE   S.IsPublic = 1
        AND S.Status = 3
        AND F.UserId = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the query you have, without the row_number as a subquery, then add the row number back later:

```
SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY subQuery.Id DESC ) rownum
FROM (
SELECT  DISTINCT S.* ,
    U.Avatar ,
    U.Displayname 
FROM    dbo.Smoothie AS S
    INNER JOIN dbo.[User] AS U ON S.UserId = U.Id
    INNER JOIN dbo.Favorite AS F ON U.Id = F.UserId
WHERE   S.IsPublic = 1
    AND S.Status = 3
    AND F.UserId = 2
) AS subQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dense_Rank` would also do the job with the your otherwise unmodified query.